# Bounds for $\sum_{t=1}^Tn_t(s_t)^{-\alpha}\mu(s_t)$ where $n_t(s) = \sum_{1 \le t' \le t} 1_{\{s_{t'}=s\}}$ for $s \in [k]$ and $\mu \in \Delta_k$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, inequalities, elementary-proofs, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Disclaimer:** I'm not certain this is the right venue for this post, but I'll give it a try...

So trying prove some bounds in my ongoing work in theoretical reinforcement learning, I encountered the need to devise and proof the following small theorem.

> **[A small Theorem]** Consider $T \ge 1$ runs of an experiment with $k \ge 1$ possible outcomes, only one of which
>   can be the observed on each run. For each run $t$, let $s_t \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$
>   be observed outcome. For each possible outcome $s \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, let $n_t(s):=\sum_{t' \le t}
> 1_{\{s_{t'} = s\}}$ be the total number of observations of $s$ in the first $t$
>   runs of the experiment. Finally, let $\mu \in \Delta_k$ be any prior
>   distribution on the outcomes, and let $\alpha \in (0, 1]$. Define
>   $E_{T}:=\sum_{t=1}^T n_t(s_t)^{-\alpha}\mu(s_t)$. We have the bound
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> E_{T}
>   \le \begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\left(\|\mu\|_{\frac{1}{\alpha}}T^{1-\alpha}-\alpha
>     \right) = \mathcal
>     O\left(T^{1-\alpha}\right), &\mbox{
>       if }0 < \alpha < 1,\\ \log(T)+ 1=\mathcal O(\log(T)),&\mbox{ if }\alpha =
>     1.\end{cases}
> \end{eqnarray}

Indeed, let $f_\alpha(x) := x^{-\alpha}$, a continuous function with anti-derivative $F_\alpha(x) :=
(1-\alpha)^{-1}x^{1-\alpha}$ if $0 < \alpha < 1$ and $g_1(x):=\log(x)$.
My proof (only sketched here for brevity) of this result is based on the pigeon-hole principle

\begin{eqnarray}
  \begin{split}
    E_{T} &:=\sum_{t=1}^Tf_\alpha(n_t(s_t))\mu(s_t)=\sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{s=1}^k
    f_\alpha(n_t(s))\mu(s)1_{\{s_t=s\}}
    =\sum_{s=1}^k\mu(s)\sum_{t=1}^Tf_\alpha(n_t(s))1_{\{s_t=s\}}\\
    &= \sum_{s=1}^k\mu(s)\sum_{n=1}^{n_T(s)} f_\alpha(n) \le 1-F_\alpha(1) +
\sum_{s=1}^k F_\alpha(n_T(s))\mu(s),
  \end{split}
  \label{eq:ph}
\end{eqnarray}
where

- where in the last equality, we have used the trick: $\{n_t(s) \mid s_t=s\} = \{1,2,\ldots,n_T(s)\}$, and
- the last inequality derives from an [elementary inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132521/sum-of-reciprocals-of-square-roots/132527#132527) relating a sum and an integral.

I then apply Hoelder's inequality on the 2nd sum: $\sum_{s=1}^k F_\alpha(n_T(s))\mu(s) \le \|F_\alpha \circ n_T\|_{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}\|\mu\|_{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$.

## Question

- Are there general tools (transforms, general inequalities, techniques, etc.) for handling quantities like $E_{T}:=\sum_{t=1}^T n_t(s_t)^{-\alpha}\mu(s_t)$ defined in the above theorem ?
- Do the above above bounds on $E_T$ look right ? Are they alarmly off ?

Any kind of feedback, input, etc. will be really appreciated. Thanks.